# Prove that if $A\subseteq B$, then $(C-B) \subseteq (C−A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that if $x$ is an element of A by definition of subsets then it is an element of $B$, but I don't know how to use the complement to prove the latter half.

Comment: I like to think these kind of problems in this way: Start from the left side of the thesis, then use the hypothesis to arrive at the right side of the thesis

Answer (score 4):

Pick an element $x \in C - B$. By definition, it is in $C$, and also it is not in $B$. Since $A \subseteq B$, $x$ is not in $A$ either. Since $x \in C$ and $x \not \in A$, $x \in C - A$ and $C - B \subseteq C - A$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in C-B$, $x\notin B$ so $x\notin A$ for otherwise suppose $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ which is a contradiction. Moreover, $x\in C$, so $x\in C-A$. By definition, we conclude that $C-B\subset C-A$.